# Local Registry for Kubernetes cluster running with containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I have a 4 node (on 4 different machines) Kubernetes cluster running over containerd (setuped with kubeadm), and i need to run some local images on this cluster but i can't find a way to create a containerd local registry to push my images to and then kubernetes to pull.

So i've tried install docker to create a docker private repository i faced a warning saying that there was a conflict with containerd, so i'm stuck and don't know another alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build with Docker and then transfer to Containerd

Sample steps:

a. Build dockerfile

```
docker build -t yourimagename .
```

b. Save image as a tar file:

```
docker save yourimagename > yourimagename.tar
```

c. Import to containerd registry

```
ctr -n=k8s.io image import yourimagename.tar
```

Comment: I've already did that, with that exact same commands, my image is shown when i run "ctr images ls" but when i try to deploy some app with the image i get the following error:

Failed to pull image "docker.io/library/myimagename:0.1": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/myimagename:0.1": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/myimagename:0.1": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Comment: I runned "crictl img" and my imported image does not appear on the output, so maybe k8s is not synced with containerd registry?

Comment: I forgot that Kubernetes uses `k8s.io` namespace in containerd. I edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I have try this with LXC images, I thought it would be same.

Export the docker image as tarball

```
lxc image export image imagek8.tar.gz
```

Then import that in docker but it have some issues

```
docker import -c 'CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]' image image:latest

docker save -o image.tar image:latest

sudo ctr -n k8s.io images import nginx-imagek8.tar
```

Comment: I also just directly try to with the last command but somehow it can't import the lxc images as i believed using different build types. What will be the optimal solution?